# In Rust, what happens if main function returns Err?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, program-entry-point, exit-code

According to [*The Rust Reference*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/crates-and-source-files.html#main-functions),

> If a `main` function is present, (snip), and its return type must be one of the following:
>
> - `()`
> - `Result<(), E> where E: Error`

but it doesn't say what happens when `main()` returns `()`, `Ok(())` or `Err(<value>)`.

As far as I tested,

|  | `()` | `Ok(())` | `Err(<value>)` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Exit Status | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Additional Behavior | - | - | `Error: <value>` is printed to `stderr` |

Are these behaviors defined, explicitly explained or guaranteed in some documentation? In particular, can I assume

- a program always exits with `1` status when `main()` returns `Err(<value>)`?
- the error message displayed when `main()` returns `Err(<value>)` is always of the form `Error: <value>`?

---

Notes:

- I want some sort of documented guarantee rather than an empirical explanation. This is why I added `#language-lawyer` tag.
- This question is not about *When should I use `()` and when should I use `Result<(), E>`?* or such. One can find answers (or at least hints or criteria) to such questions in many documentations or tutorials, as you know.

---

Updates:

`Termination` trait is finally stabilized in Rust 1.61.0 ([source](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/05/19/Rust-1.61.0.html#stabilized-apis)).

Comment: The [`Termination`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/trait.Termination.html) trait plays a central role here. Unfortunately, it doesn't document this behavior either. My guess would be that it's simply currently not documented/guaranteed anywhere except in those `Termination for Result` impls.

Comment: And here is the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1937-ques-in-main.md) for the `Termination` trait.

Comment: Well the `Termination` docs do state that: "_The default implementations are returning `libc::EXIT_SUCCESS` to indicate a successful execution. In case of a failure, `libc::EXIT_FAILURE` is returned,_" so that part can probably be relied on (as much as any unstable feature can be). The error printing OTOH appears undocumented (although implied by the `E: Debug` bounds on the `impl Termination for Result<…>` declarations).

Comment: Since the behavior is documented only in an unstable type (and even then not fully, e.g. it delegates to the lower-level `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` and fails to document the exact output), you can't assume either of those things, and should format the output and call `std::process::exit()` yourself. Of course, the behavior is extremely unlikely to change _in practice_, as that would be a backward-incompatible change, but from a language-lawyer perspective, you simply don't (yet) get the guarantees you're asking about.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The behavior of different return values from `main` is defined by the [`std::process::Termination`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/trait.Termination.html) trait:

> `trait std::process::Termination`
>
> A trait for implementing arbitrary return types in the main function.

This trait is documented to return `libc::EXIT_SUCCESS` on success and `libc::EXIT_FAILURE` on error.

> The default implementations are returning `libc::EXIT_SUCCESS` to indicate a successful execution. In case of a failure, `libc::EXIT_FAILURE` is returned.

But those values [aren't guaranteed to be 0 and 1 on non-POSIX systems](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html).

---

As for printing the error message, `Termination` requires `E: Debug` and does print the `Debug` impl to stderr, but I don't believe it's guaranteed to stay exactly the same.

```rust
impl<E: fmt::Debug> Termination for Result<!, E> {
    fn report(self) -> ExitCode {
        let Err(err) = self;
        eprintln!("Error: {:?}", err);
        ExitCode::FAILURE.report()
    }
}
```

[Source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/process.rs.html#2071-2077)

Answer (score 9):

This behavior is controlled by the [`std::process::Termination`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/trait.Termination.html) Trait, which was added in [RFC 1937](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1937-ques-in-main.md). In particular, the "hidden" `lang_start()` function - which calls `main()` - looks roughly like:

```rust
fn lang_start<T: Termination>(
    main: fn() -> T,
    argc: isize,
    argv: *const *const u8
) -> !
```

that is, `main()` can return any `T: Termination`. There are [implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/trait.Termination.html#implementors) of `Termination` in `std` for `!`, `()`, `std::process:ExitCode`, and some `Result<T, E>`-variants where `E: Debug`. This is why you can return `()`, `Ok(())` and others from `main()`.

To your question, language lawyer mode: The exact behavior of any program that relies on `Termination` is not strictly specified by the language itself. It is part of the `std` implementation, not part of the language reference. That means that the same program *might* behave differently when compiled with different versions of the compiler (binding to different `std` versions). The exact behavior for printing errors in the `Err` case is *[documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/error/struct.Report.html#return-from-main)* but not specified. As RFC 1937 explicitly looks for POSIX-like behavior, you can be reasonably assured that the program will not behave in wildly suprising ways (e.g. exit with status `0` in an `Err`-case).