# Getting the anyhow Rust crate to format an error like it does when when exiting the main function

Tags: rust, error-handling, anyhow

Adding the `anyhow` crate to a blank Rust project and running the following code gives you the output `Error: error`, which I want:

```rust
use anyhow::anyhow;

fn error() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    Err(anyhow!("error"))
}

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    error()
}
```

However, running the following code only outputs `error`:

```rust
use anyhow::anyhow;

fn error() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    Err(anyhow!("error"))
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(error) = error() {
        println!("{:?}", error);
    }
}
```

I also tried using `"{}"` instead, but that also only lead to `error` being printed.

The documentation says the following:

> The Debug format “{:?}” includes your backtrace if one was captured. Note that this is the representation you get by default if you return an error from `fn main` instead of printing it explicitly yourself.
>
> ```
> Error: Failed to read instrs from ./path/to/instrs.json
>
> Caused by:
>     No such file or directory (os error 2)
> ```

I couldn't find the part of the source code that added the extra `Error:` , otherwise I could probably figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra `Error:`  is not related to anyhow, but rather how `main()` behaves if the returned `Result` is an `Err`. You can find the exact code within the [implementation of `Termination` for `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/trait.Termination.html#impl-Termination-for-Result%3CT%2C%20E%3E):

```
impl<T: Termination, E: fmt::Debug> Termination for Result<T, E> {
    fn report(self) -> ExitCode {
        match self {
            Ok(val) => val.report(),
            Err(err) => {
                io::attempt_print_to_stderr(format_args_nl!("Error: {err:?}"));
                ExitCode::FAILURE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if you want `Error:`  included in the output in a different context, you'll have to add it yourself.

See also: [In Rust, what happens if main function returns Err?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72054026/in-rust-what-happens-if-main-function-returns-err)